# Downloading a Gzip'd file

Tags: node.js

I'm attempting to download a file using the http module in node.  While the file seems to download sucessfully, the resultant file cannot be opened using gzip.  I've tried downloading the file through other methods, and that works, and I've tried using multiple ways to open the resultant gzip'd file, but all of those produce the same error.

I did attempt to use the request module, but there seemed to be no way of accessing the returned HTTP headers before the file was finished downloading, which I need because I'd like to offer some sort of visual indicator as to how long this file is going to take to download.

This is (roughly) the code that I've got so far.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var progress = 0;

downloadFile = function() {
    http.get(FILE_URL, function(response) {
        var maxBytes = parseInt(response.headers['content-length'], 10);
        var dumpFile = fs.createWriteStream(FILENAME + '.dl');
        response.pipe(dumpFile);

        response
            .on('data', function(chunk) {
                progress += chunk.length;
                // progressbar-type code here
            })
            .on('end', function() {
                // pass
            })

        dumpFile.on('finish', function() {
            dumpFile.close();
            fs.rename(FILENAME + '.dl', FILENAME);
    });
}
```

So my question:  How would you advise I download a file, bearing in mind it's a large file and I need some sort of visual indicator for download progress?  Should I give up on http?  Or am I doing something monumentally stupid?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you take out the progress bar stuff (the `on('data')` and `on('end')` stuff)?  I can't remember if you can use them in conjunction with pipe or not...

Comment: Ooh look!  It now works!  :P  Thanks, it turns out I was doing something monumentally stupid.